# My NavigationView won't show in DrawerLayout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

This is the first time I creating navigation in android studio, I already created the navigation header and drawer menu(they both showing in their own xml), but none of them appearing in my activity_home.xml(only Android..DrawerLayout text appears) , it even says that my header is empty, did I miss something??

**This is the activity_home.xml**

> ```
>    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>        android:layout_width="match_parent"
>        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
>        android:elevation="4dp"/>
>
>    <FrameLayout
>        android:layout_width="match_parent"
>        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>
> ```
>
> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_gravity="start"
>     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
>     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_heqader" *(This line said that xml tag has empty body)*
>     app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
> ```

**This is the nav_heqader.xml(slightly typo here)**

> ```
> >
>
> <ImageView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
> />
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:paddingTop="8dp"
>     android:text="Test"
>     android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
>     />
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Testing"/>
> ```

**This is the drawer_menu.xml**

> ```
> <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_message"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
>         android:title="Message" />
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_chat"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
>         android:title="Chat" />
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
>         android:title="Profile" />
> </group>
>
> <item android:title="Communicate">
>     <menu>
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_share"
>             android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
>             android:title="Profilez" />
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_share2"
>             android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
>             android:title="Profilezd" />
>     </menu>
> </item>
> ```

**This is the Home.java**

```
package com.example.aldyro.movie;


import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

**This is the styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**This is the module:app (just in case my version isn't compatible)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aldyro.movie"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

**So sorry I can't directly show the pic since I'm new here**

[**nav_heqader screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJMY6.png)

[**drawer_menu screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glBf2.png)

[**activity_home screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR2DU.png)

Comment: Are you talking about the layout editor in Android Studio? Or do you mean that your drawer doesn't work when you run the app?

Comment: I think its only preview issue. It should work in device when you run. And in preview also it may be giving some rendering issue, re building project can solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of documentation out there for this question.

This link provide documentation of using a Navigation Drawer in Fragment, not Activity as u asking, but its very helpfull, if u are new to Android is a very good point to start.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: Thanks! i'll take a look later

Answer (score 1):

You can create new activity from templates available and remove your old activity.

```
To insert new activity with drawer select File -> New -> acitivity -> Navigation drawer activity.
```

You will need to change your menu entries as required.

Answer (score 0):

The Drawer and the navigation menu shows when you swipe from left of the screen.

[Swipe from left to show the drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBJLw.png) (link to image)

You need to setDisplayShowHomeEnabled
and on the click you need to manage the drawer
open and close drawer.

[Video link to your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBJLw.png)

Comment: I have added the video link. It is the same code to you have written above